# Como passar valor vindo do service para var?

Tags: rest, vue.js

Possuo um serviço REST para buscar os valores do visitante. Porém, não consigo manipular os valores vindos do serviço fora da *promise*.

```
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      visitor: {}
    }
  }
}

created(){
   this.VisitorService.show(this.visitorStorage)
      .then(visitor => {
        this.visitor = visitor;
        console.log(this.visitor);
        // dentro da promise ok, apresenta o valor.
      }).catch(error =>{
      console.log(error);
    });

    console.log(this.visitor);
    // fora, imprime somente o objeto
}
```

Alguém possui alguma ideia do que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Resultado impresso dentro da *promisse*

[image: Resultado impresso dentro da *promisse*]

Resultado que é impresso fora da *promisse*

[image: Resultado que é impresso fora da *promisse*]

Comment: Tem como mostrar o que tá sendo apresentado em cada caso?

Comment: @LINQ Inclui duas imagens com as saídas

Comment: Esse `created` está fora do objeto, devia estar depois do `data()`. Acho que é só esse o problema do teu código. O que é esse `this.VisitorService`? como estás a adicioná-lo ao objeto do Vue?

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando o escopo this dentro da promise, isto faz com que não seja utilizando o escopo do Vue e logo, sua variável não receberá o valor. Crie um ponto de acesso ao escopo do Vue com o nome de outra variável e utilize este ponto para fazer a associação posteriormente. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      visitor: {}
    }
  }
}

created() {
  var self = this;

  this.VisitorService.show(this.visitorStorage)
    .then(visitor => {
      self.visitor = visitor;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  // Não pode ser utilizado o console.log logo após uma requisição
  // pois você não tem certeza que a chamada foi finalizada...
  // o correto é utilizar dentro do then da promise como fez.
  // console.log(this.visitor);
}
```

Fazendo desta forma, o visitor será alimentado no vue e assim, tendo efeito no html caso o esteja utilizando. O que não pode é utilizar a chamada do console.log fora do escopo da promise esperando que ele tenha o valor correto. A promise serve exatamente pra isso, mas para acessar o escopo do Vue, você precisa antes armazenar em uma variável sua instância pois o this será dentro do contexto da promise e não do vue.

Comment: Na verdade eu havia declarado o visitor já dentro do data(). Irei editar para deixar esta informação junto do exemplo. também seguindo conforme o seu exemplo, acaba retornando o componente..

Comment: Fiz uma atualização, veja se ficou melhor para entender.